# I need to assign two IP's in two Nic's in one server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

can some one help me in assigning a static ip on two nic's in one server?

NIC 1: 10.110.180.110 | 255.255.255.0 | 10.110.180.1
NIC 2: 10.124.11.60 | | 255.255.255.0

i am using a window server 2008 r2 both ip needs to be reachable

can i have the step by step procedure on how to do it with the commands? is it via netsh?

Comment: Do you need one for LAN and second for WAN only ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, why it didn't work etc.

Answer (score 3):

To assign IP via netsh:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address
```

An example to this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address “NIC1” 10.110.180.110 255.255.255.0
```

To assign additional IP just type the same command with the new parametres.

There is also a way to add multiple IP addresses at once. I guess you might be interested in it:

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

Answer (score 1):

So assigning IP should not be difficult and was already covered in other answers. However requirement of both IPs should be reachable is a tricky one.
How multihomed servers work - there is one NIC in a subnet with default gateway and other NICs are set without gateways.
Let's illustrate it on example:

```
                +--------+
                | router |
                +--+-----+                             +----------+
                   |    10.0.0.254                     |          |
This subnet has default gateway                        | Server 2 |
                   |   10.0.0.1/24                     | 10.0.1.2/24
             +-----+------+                            +---+------+
             |            |                                |
             |    Server  +------------------------+-------++
             |      1     |10.0.1.1/24             |
             |            |                        |
             +------------+                        | 10.0.1.254
                                           +-------+---------+
                                           |     router      |
                                           +------+----------+
                                                  | 10.0.3.254
                                                  |
                                                  |
                                                  |  10.0.3.1/24
                                            +-----+---------+
                                            |               |
                                            |    Server 3   |
                                            |               |
                                            +---------------+
```

We have 3 subnets:
Subnet 1 : 10.0.0.0/24
Subnet 2 : 10.0.1.0/24
Subnet 3 : 10.0.3.0/24

Server 1 is example of multihomed server, in other words exactly what you are looking for.
It's NIC 1 is in Subnet 1 and this one is setup with gateway IP 10.0.0.254
It's 2nd NIC is in subnet 2.

Now what that means:
If Server 1 wants to contact Server 2 - it will choose NIC 2, since it's directly attached network and has highest routing priority. In other words IP address of Server 2 is on the same subnet that NIC2 of Server 1.
However if Server 1 wants to contact Server 3 - there is no specifically set route for it and it's not on a directly attached network. So Default gateway 10.0.0.254 will be chosen.
Same applies if Server 3 wants to communicate with Server 1 NIC1 10.0.0.1. Server 3 will use it's own default gateway.
However if Server 3 want's to communicate with IP of NIC 2 - 10.0.1.1. - that won't work. Traffic pattern will go this way
Server 3 -> 10.0.3.254 -> 10.0.1.254 -> 10.0.1.1 So packets reach Server 1 NIC 2. But what happens next is going to be an issue.
Server 1 receives on NIC2 packets from Server 3 - however now is the routing decision. How to send replies?
There is no specifically set route for subnet 10.0.3.0/24. 
So Server 1 will chose to reply via it's default gateway and NIC1.
These packets will reach Server 3 - however TCP communication will not be established as there will be a mismatch in source address.

```
10.0.3.1+----------> 10.0.1.1
  ^                  10.0.0.1
  |                     +
  +---------------------+
```

In the linux world - there is a solution that exists though rarely used. It's called "policy routing". In a nut shell this allows to setup routing decisions based on which NIC traffic was received.
For the above example it would be something like this
If Server 1 receives traffic on NIC2 - don't use default gateway, but send replies back via gateway of subnet 2.
I'm not aware of such analogue in Windows world.
So as far as I can tell - setting it up so that both IPs are accessible from remote hosts is not going to be possible.
You can set it up in a way that Server 3 will access Server 1 via Server 1 NIC2 IP by introducing static routes on Server 1, but then you will lose possibility to access from Server 3 NIC1 of Server 1.